# Setting AnsiWarnings to 'OFF' is not supported on Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

I get the message below when executing `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`.

```
Msg 104409, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Setting AnsiWarnings to 'OFF' is not supported.
```

A similar message happens with `SET ARITHABORT OFF`. Setting the options to `ON` executes the command without errors happening.  Everything I find on Microsoft websites indicates this is supported on a Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

My goal is to suppress division by zero errors without requiring changes to the SQL syntax by users. We've used this option successfully on SQL Server databases for years.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Data Warehouse only supports setting these values to ON. If you try to set these ON (SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON) you aren't changing the supported behavior. When you try and set these to OFF, you will see the warning as expected.